# Using Function for addition

Tags: function, verilog

I am trying to use functions in Verilog to repeat a specific code logic which is Addition. I want to use a 4-bit binary adder in a function. I tried the following in Vivado, but it is strange that the output always has a one-bit value:

```
module my_divider(A,B,Sum); 

input [3:0] A;
input [3:0] B;
output [3:0] Sum;

function do_addition;
    input  [3:0] int_A,int_B; 
    reg   [3:0] v_Temp; // Local Variable
    begin    
       v_Temp = A + B;
       do_addition=v_Temp[3:0];
    end
  endfunction


assign Sum[3:0] = do_addition(A,B);
endmodule
```

Testbench is below:

```
module div_tb;

reg [3:0] A,B;
wire [3:0] Sum;
my_divider DUT(.A(A),.B(B),.Sum(Sum));

initial
begin
A=4'b0000;
B=4'b0000;
#50;
A=4'b0010;
B=4'b0001;
#50
A=4'b0001;
B=4'b1000;
end

initial
#150
$finish;

endmodule
```

output:
[image]

Is there something which I am missing?

The output is either 0 or 1. Is there some limitation of functions that I could pass only one bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the function with a bit width:

```
function [3:0] do_addition;
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2012, *13.4 Functions*:

> In particular, the implicit syntax can be empty, in which case the
>   return type is a logic **scalar**.